# How to do colouring the contents of a mail while sending via unix terminal using mailx command?

Tags: email

I have a file(.txt) with below details(I am having more than 50 files but listed only 4) and while sending that file via mail I want to implement some coloring to it. I am not sure while it is possible or not, Could you please help me on this please ?

```
date    filename_now    avg_timestamp    space    count    status
Nov 4    CHCK01_20161104.txt    06:39    2.15M    17153    Delayed    -->    RED
Nov 4    TRIPS11_20161104.txt    09:03    0.00M    024    On_Time    -->    GREEN
Nov 4    AR02_20161104.txt    09:31    0.00M    007    No_Files    -->    YELLOW
Nov 4    AR01_20161104.txt    09:31    0.04M    433    Delayed    -->    RED
```

This it I am getting in my mail(MS outlook), Can I implement coloring for the status field as requested?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Cannot you realize that the `coloring` is related to the recipient's e-mail client (MS outlook), not the UNIX command used to send it?

Comment: okay, Can you suggest me how can I implement HTML in my unix script or how to get rid of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is surround your lines with HTML font tags based on the value of the status column, this awk code should do the trick:

```
{
    if ( /On_Time/ ) print "<font color=\"#00FF00\">", $0, "</font>"
    if ( /Delayed/ ) print "<font color=\"#FF0000\">", $0, "</font>"
    if ( /No_Files/ ) print "<font color=\"#FFFF00\">", $0, "</font>"
}
```